# O else não é reconhecido

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: Estou aprendendo JS]

```
   alert("");
            var n1=parseInt(prompt("Digite um número"));
            var n2=parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número"));
            var A = n1+n2;
            var M = n1*n2;
            var D = n1/n2;
            var Sub = n1-n2;

            var menu=prompt("Escolha uma opção:\nA - Adição\nM - Multiplicação\nD - Divisão \nS - Subtração")

            if(menu == A);{
                alert(A);
            }else(menu == M);{
                alert(M);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns problemas no seu código:

1. Não há ponto e vírgula (`;`) após `if` e `else`;
2. Como você está tentando comparar com o valor do `prompt` digitado pelo usuário, a letra A seria uma String, logo deve ser colocada entre aspas, senão o javascript irá procurar uma variável com o nome A, ao contrário da própria letra A.
3. No caso do `else` não há uma condição dentro. Pense no `else` como *senão todas as outras opções*. Caso queira colocar uma condição, poderia utilizar o `else if`, porém no seu caso não é necessário.

Segue abaixo seu exemplo funcionando bem simples o seu menu, com `if`, `else if` e `else`, prevendo todos os seus casos.

```js
var n1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número"));
var n2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número"));
var A = n1 + n2;
var M = n1 * n2;
var D = n1 / n2;
var Sub = n1 - n2;

var menu=prompt("Escolha uma opção:\nA - Adição\nM - Multiplicação\nD - Divisão \nS - Subtração")

if (menu === 'A') {
  alert(A);
} else if (menu === 'M') {
  alert(M);
} else if (menu === 'D') {
  alert(D);
} else {
  alert(Sub);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Maniero, ajudou demais

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria aprender de forma estruturada, entender o porquê de cada coisa.

Não pode ter ponto e vírgula  depois da condição do `if` ou `else`. O `;` encerra uma declaração, e todo o bloco do `if` é uma declaração única.

Além disto quando vai colocar uma condição no `else` deve vir seguido de um `if`.

Por fima quando você vai comparar uma variável com um texto, o texto deve estar entre aspas, senão é interpretado como variável.

Tem uma série de outras coisas que podem ser melhoradas neste código.

```js
var n1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número"));
var n2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número"));
var A = n1 + n2;
var M = n1 * n2;
var D = n1 / n2;
var Sub = n1 - n2;
var menu = prompt("Escolha uma opção:\nA - Adição\nM - Multiplicação\nD - Divisão \nS - Subtração")
if (menu == "A") {
    alert(A);
} else if (menu == "M") {
    alert(M);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Option.js).